# What is the right way to do recursion inside foreach loop using typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, recursion

**Scenario**

I'm trying to create a custom typewriting effect [Like this](http://slimhamdi.net/moscow/demos/index-light.html) with 100ms delay in angular.

Below is my typescript code:

```
private arr: string[] = ["Lead Developer (.NET)", "Full Stack (.NET) Developer", "Freelancer"];
private typewriter_text: string = "";
private typewriter_display: string = ""; 

ngOnInit() {
    this.typingInitiating(this);
  }

  typingInitiating(that) {
    this.arr.forEach(element => {
      that.typewriter_text = element;
      this.typingCallback(that);
    });
  }

  typingCallback(that) {
    if (this.typewriter_display.length < that.typewriter_text.length) {
      this.typewriter_display += that.typewriter_text[this.typewriter_display.length];  
      setTimeout(that.typingCallback, 100, that);
    }
    else {
      for (let i = that.typewriter_text.length; i >= 0; --i) {
        this.typewriter_display = that.replaceAt(that.typewriter_text, i,that.typewriter_text.length - i);
        console.log(this.typewriter_display)
      }
    }
  }

  replaceAt(text: string, index: number, charcount: number): string {
    return text.substr(0, index) + text.substr(index + charcount);
  }
```

In my App.Component.html:

```
{{typewriter_display }}
```

**Live Stackblitz**

I'm facing an error in console:

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqtvoz

I want to know why my recursion is not working as expected.

Comment: It works well in stackblitz

Comment: Yes, because I did those changes.

Comment: you shouldn't use setTimeout in angular. Use the appropriate rxjs operator to perform the action repeatedly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is lost in your function and does not refer to the object itself. Every function created has it's own `this`. We will need to change it to **Arrow function** because it does not bind its own this.

```
typingCallback = (that:any) => {

 if (this.typewriter_display.length < that.typewriter_text.length) {
  this.typewriter_display += 
  that.typewriter_text[this.typewriter_display.length];  
  setTimeout(that.typingCallback, 100, that);
}
else {
  for (let i = that.typewriter_text.length; i >= 0; --i) {
    this.typewriter_display = that.replaceAt(that.typewriter_text, 
   i,that.typewriter_text.length - i);
     console.log(this.typewriter_display)
   }
 }

};
```